# Why is modal presentation form sheet not being displayed as expected?

Tags: ios, ipad, modalviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I'm just trying a really simple example here as I start to delve into iOS development for ipad.

I'm creating a split view and immediately trying to present a modal form sheet.
Should be really basic.

With what I've tried I get what behaves like a page sheet instead.
In landscape I can see the split view beneath but I don't see the top of my modal view (the tool bar is hidden but is in view in portrait).

I would expect to just grey out the split view beneath a 540x620 modal dialog. I should see the split view beneath my modal in both portrait and landscape like all the nice form sheet dialogs in the Cheddar app for example.

I must be doing something wrong here but all the examples I've read and same within the Cheddar app are doing pretty much what I outline below.

In the app delegate:

```
    MasterViewController *masterViewController = [[MasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MasterViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *masterNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:masterViewController];

DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *detailNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detailViewController];

masterViewController.detailViewController = detailViewController;

self.splitViewController = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];
self.splitViewController.delegate = detailViewController;
self.splitViewController.viewControllers = @[masterNavigationController, detailNavigationController];
self.window.rootViewController = self.splitViewController;

[self.window addSubview:self.splitViewController.view];

ModalViewController *modalView = [[ModalViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ModalViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:modalView];
navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;

[self.splitViewController presentViewController:navController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Comment: I posted an answer to a similar question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10104706/present-modal-form-sheet-over-modal-page-sheet/22103328#22103328

Comment: I posted an answer to a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10104706/present-modal-form-sheet-over-modal-page-sheet/22103328#22103328

Comment: I answered a similar question [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10104706/present-modal-form-sheet-over-modal-page-sheet/22103328#22103328

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app delegate is way too soon. You have no interface yet, so you can't coherently do any presenting of any view controller.

So, first thing, move all your `modalView` code to the `viewDidAppear:` of your `detailViewController`.

Comment: welp, I moved the modal stuff to the detail:viewDidLoad and I get the same results.

Comment: I didn't say `viewDidLoad` did I? In `viewDidLoad` there is still no interface! Please try what I actually said to try.

Comment: What, indeed, d'ya know. Might help to read my book's chapter on view controllers: it explains clearly what the events mean (and a bunch of other stuff): http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch19.html

Comment: awesome, for sure. much obliged.

Comment: so by "there is no interface" you literally mean no UI view objects or anything has been loaded yet at say the app delegate level?

Comment: UIView objects can exist without being in the interface. They are just objects, but the interface is the actual subviews of your app's window. If the UIView's `window` is not the app's window, it literally is not in the interface.

Comment: And when you are initially manipulating a view controller, it may well have no view at all, let alone a view in the interface.